# How to load scss variables and fonts file from node_modules in Vite

Tags: sass, vite

I am using `nuxt-vite` in a SSR nuxt project, here is my code

**nuxt.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    css: [
        '~/assets/fonts.scss',
    ]
}
```

I want to use `@mdi/font` in my project, and here is where it located in node_modules:
[image]

---

1. First, I try to import the css directly:

```
@import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css
```

But the browser can not find the fonts files
[image]

2. Then, I try to load the raw scss variables just like what I did when using webpack whick works without any issues.

```
@import "@mdi/font/scss/variables";
@import "@mdi/font/scss/functions";
@font-face {
    font-family: '#{$mdi-font-name}';
    src: url('@mdi/font/fonts/#{$mdi-filename}-webfont.eot?v=#{$mdi-version}');
    src: url('@mdi/font/fonts/#{$mdi-filename}-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=#{$mdi-version}') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('@mdi/font/fonts/#{$mdi-filename}-webfont.woff2?v=#{$mdi-version}') format('woff2'),
        url('@mdi/font/fonts/#{$mdi-filename}-webfont.woff?v=#{$mdi-version}') format('woff'),
        url('@mdi/font/fonts/#{$mdi-filename}-webfont.ttf?v=#{$mdi-version}') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@import "@mdi/font/scss/core";
@import "@mdi/font/scss/icons";
@import "@mdi/font/scss/extras";
@import "@mdi/font/scss/animated";
```

But the vite can not load the scss variables correctly:
[image]

How can I use the fonts in node_modules when using vite?

I googled it and read the doc but helped little.

Greate thanks to anyone help!

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

add this to `nuxt.config.js`

```js
vite: {
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          additionalData: `@import "~/assets/styles/Variables.scss";\n@import "~/assets/styles/Mixins.scss";\n`
        }
      }
    }
  },
```